# Times by $2\pi$ to find surface area using arc length

Tags: surfaces

I am trying to find the surface area of a 'biconcave disc', which is the shape of a red blood cell. I know the formula/length for the curve, which I am integrating to find the volume of the shape.  To find the surface area of the shape, can I just multiply this length by $2 \pi$?

Following is the shape and curve I am talking about, with the first part showing a cross section of the 3D object, and the second showing the curve I am talking about.

[image: A biconcave disc]

I basically took the second curve and integrated it around the x-axis to find the volume.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you mean by "formula/length for the curve". You have a three-dimensional object with volume; what curve are you looking at? Perhaps it would be better if you would show everything that you are doing to find the volume; that might at least clarify what it is you intend to multiply by $2\pi$.

Comment: Look at the Area formula in wiki's entry of [Surface of revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution).

Comment: Your curve on the right is **not** the cross-section of the figure on the left!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. This follows already from the fact that it scales incorrectly – if you scale the whole thing up by $\lambda$, that quantity would scale with $\lambda$ whereas it should scale with $\lambda^2$.

Each curve element sweeps a surface area element of different radius. The correct way to take this into account is given in the Wikipedia article that achille hui linked to in a comment.